# Determine in which points function is continuous

Tags: calculus, limits, continuity

We have function $f$ that behaves like this: if $x \not= 0$ and it is represented as ratio of $p$ and $q$ where $p \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $q \in \mathbb{N}$ , then $f(x) = 1/q$. Otherwise, $f(x) = 0$. IMPORTANT: $\gcd(p, q) = 1$

So, In my opinion, It is convenient to use definition of continuous function that involves sequences.

So, it seems like as $x$ tends to 0, $f(x)$ tends 0 too. And even in general case for $x$ that tends to $a$ it also may be the case. However, I am not sure how to prove it formally. For $x$ tends to 0, we have to prove that for all sequences $\{x_n\}$ such that $x_n$ tend to 0 as $n$ tends to infinity are such that $f(x_n)$ tends to 0. Maybe after that we could use this one in other cases or something like that?

All help will be much appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Comment: The function, as stated, is not well defined. If $x = 1/2 = 2/4$ what is $f(x)$?

Comment: It's not the case for rational $p/q$: the constant sequence $x_n=p/q$ tends to $p/q$, so $f(x_n)$ tends to $1/q$.
Hint: this function is continuous in the irrationals, discontinuous in the rationals.

Comment: @jjagmath I edited question, now, I think, it is well defined